# JavaScript Redirect to URL after calling ng-click function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have one below link

```
<a ng-click="logout()"><i class="fa fa-sign-out" name="sign-out"></i> Logout</a>
```

I want that when I click on this link first they called their `logout()` function then they will redirect to the below page

```
https://demo.testlab.local/
```

The problem is that client **don't want to change their code for logout() method**. But I can ReWrite anything on this link code only `<a ng-click="logout()"><i class="fa fa-sign-out" name="sign-out"></i> Logout</a>`.

So Is their any solution for this.

Comment: Just assign some other function, then call `logout()` in your own function, then redirect. Where exactly is the problem? You are allowed to add functions, right?

Comment: @user3441151 You will be using routing in your app are using `ngRoute` or `ui-router`?

Comment: @NarenMurali I already mentioned in my question, I cannot change anything into their code except the link code `<a ng-click="logout()"><i class="fa fa-sign-out" name="sign-out"></i> Logout</a>`

Comment: @ChrisG Can I call the js function that is written in index.html file not in any controller by modifying the `<a ng-click="logout()"><i class="fa fa-sign-out" name="sign-out"></i> Logout</a>`

Answer (score 1):

Use below code:

```
<a ng-click="logout()" ng-href="https://demo.testlab.local/"><i class="fa fa-sign-out" name="sign-out"></i> Logout</a>
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: No, I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they won't change logout(), even to add in an argument to pass to it, and assuming that you want the same functionality to happen that is in logout(), the best thing is to make a new method and then call it after logout:

```
<a ng-click="logout(); newLogout()"></a>
```

And the method then is straightforward:

```
newLogout() {
  this.$state.go(); // Using ui-router to move
  this.window.location = ""; // Using plain javascript
}
```

You did mention that you can "rewrite anything on the link only" so perhaps you can't even change the controller?

Comment: I cannot change anything on their code. But only change `<a ng-click="logout()"><i class="fa fa-sign-out" name="sign-out"></i> Logout</a>`

Comment: Can I call the js function that is written in `index.html` file not in any controller by modifying the `<a ng-click="logout()"><i class="fa fa-sign-out" name="sign-out"></i> Logout</a>`

Answer (score 0):

**You can use button tag inside a form, When button submits you can redirect to the link**

```
<form action="https://demo.testlab.local/">
  <input type="submit" value="Logout" onclick="logout()"/>
</form>
```

Comment: I already mentioned in my question, I cannot change anything into their code except the link code `<a ng-click="logout()"><i class="fa fa-sign-out" name="sign-out"></i> Logout</a>`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, but it's really bad:

```
<a ng-click="logout()" onclick="setTimeout(function () { console.log('changing location'); }, 1000);">Logout</a>
```

Just insert the code you want to run in place of `console.log('changing location');`

Edit:
What you actually need is this:

```
<a ng-click="logout()" onclick="setTimeout(function () { window.location = 'https://demo.testlab.local/'; }, 1000);">Logout</a>
```

Comment: Yes I can see inside message in the console.

Comment: Great, now replace `console.log('changing location');` with `window.location = 'https://demo.testlab.local/';`

Comment: Here "1000" is the timeout, but how they will work. They wait for some time after they will redirect to other page?

Comment: Yes, it's the number of milliseconds. A timeout of `1000` means JS waits exactly one second before it runs the code.

Comment: Neither. The code inside the function that is passed to `setTimeout()` as first parameter.